# Systemd service that runs only for one user and as root

Tags: systemd, services

## What I want to do

Essentially I want to do this

```
~/.config/systemd/user/me_unit.service
-----------------------
[Unit]
Description="Unmount thing"

[Service]
User=root
Group=root
ExecStop=/home/failuregod/.config/systemd/user/unmount.py
RemainAfterExit=yes

[Install]
WantedBy=default.target
```

## What I tried

`sudo systemd --user enable me_unit.service`

This doesn't work. I get the following error `Failed to connect to bus: No such file or directory.`

I also tried without sudo but then I'm not allowed to switch the user to root (understandably)

## What I'm trying to do

I triple (or more) boot my computer and I want all my linux partitions to use the same Documents and Downloads folders but different homes. My spectacular idea was to use zfs and make multiple home datasets and one Docuemnt and one Downloads dataset.

The initial unlock will be done with pam_exec but I was hoping to use systemd to unmount the datasets. I want to avoid, if possible, having to like somehow stuff my username into the unit then check for usernames in the unmount script.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure why this needs to be a service. I'm assuming that for each OS, you are the only user using these common folders, and if other users exist, they don't access your ~/Documents/.
If you've created separate volumes for Downloads and Documents, and for each OS, fstab mounts Downloads and Documents to your user's ~/Downloads and ~/Documents, does that not accomplish your objective?

Comment: To the best of my knowledge fstab doesn't work with zfs. Furthermore cause of how zfs works I need to export the pools (or logoff) or whatever before I switch os's. I thought the best way to do that was with a service but if you have other ideas if be interested to hear them.

Comment: sorry, my mistake. I'm weak on ZFS.  My other thought was, why multi boot, when you could use KVM/QEMU to host VMs and use your multiple OS's concurrently w/o having to reboot, but I'm sure there are reasons for your methods.